# Submitting a Job using the Sun Grid Engine

Tags: cluster-computing, jobs, job-scheduling

I am trying to submit a job using the Sun Grid Engine to a cluster (runs CentOS 6.3) for the first time. I have a simple program that I want to run on 12 cores on the cluster. I wrote the following .job file

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe smp 12
#$ -q SB
#$ -j y
#$ -o out

module load intel/13.1.0
ifort -openmp omp_hello.f -o hello
hello
```

where I have specified the parallel environment using -pe smp 12. It seems that the fortran code compiled ok since I can see the executable file after the job runs, however the code was not executed and the output/error file from the job gave me the following:

```
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/neon-compute-3-13/job_scripts/2569924: line 10: hello: command not found
```

Is there something that I have done wrong? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use ./hello to execute the file. The modified .job file looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe smp 12
#$ -q SB
#$ -j y
#$ -o out

module load intel/13.1.0
ifort -openmp omp_hello.f -o hello
./hello
```